# Why does the optimize.curve_fit not work on smaller datasets?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, linear-regression, piecewise

I have performed a piecewise linear fit for my data `H2O` and `CO2`. It works perfectly fine for a dataset of `288` data points but not for a dataset of `144` data points. My code is as following:

```
#Piecewiselinear fit
x = np.array(H2O)
y = np.array(CO2)
p , e = optimize.curve_fit(piecewise_linear, x, y)
xd = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
```

With the data set of `144` data points, the only difference occurs when running `optimize.curve_fit`. I get the following message `OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated category=OptimizeWarning`. And these are the different plots:
[Correct fit (288 points)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obMz7.png) and [Incorrect fit (144 points)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEN7B.png)

What goes wrong? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the approach from the common

```
def piecewise_linear(x, x0, y0, k1, k2):
    return np.piecewise(x, [x < x0], [lambda x:k1*x + y0-k1*x0, lambda x:k2*x + y0-k2*x0])
```

to

```
my_pwlf = pwlf.PiecewiseLinFit(x, y)
breaks = my_pwlf.fit(2) #if you want multiple breakpoints change the number in the bracket.
print(breaks)

x_hat = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)
y_hat = my_pwlf.predict(x_hat)
```

Hereby, I also got the x-value of the breakpoint.